# iOS 5 Library/Caches purge callback

Tags: ios, ios5

Is it possible for the Caches directory to be purged while my app is running, and if so, will my app be notified in any way that this has occured?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible for the cleaning to occur while it is running (though my impression is no).  However if you want to detect when the cleaning has occurred you can set a test file into the caches directory and check for it's presence.

File Gone = Cache Purged

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the docs:

> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. **This will never occur while an app is running.** However, you should be aware that iTunes restore is not necessarily the only condition under which the Caches directory can be erased.